# Problem with conversation decimal to hex value for SendMessage

Tags: c#, memory, hex, decimal

I'm trying to understand what the rule is for converting hex int (decimal) and IntrPtr.

I read somewhere that it should represent the "higher memory" or something like that.

If someone could explain that to me a bit, it would be great.

But actually it's just about the following:

I want to use SendMessage to send [APPCOMMAND_SAVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-appcommand) (int value 32).

```
const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
```

MS docs says #define WM_APPCOMMAND / 0x**0**319 But that doesn't seem to make any difference. I have somehow problems with the zero signs. How ever 0x319 works.

So I found out that e.g. vol up is:

```
const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000; // 10
```

Now I'm trying to convert APPCOMMAND_SAVE (32) to the right hex value:

```
const int APPCOMMAND_SAVE = 0x200000; //? Hex value of 32 is the right?
```

Comment: A hex value of `0x0319` is identical to `0x319`, in the same way that `01000` is equal to `1000`.  We just typically drop the leading `0`s because they serve no purpose

Comment: Yeah that's what confuses me. In which number system is the 10 from ms docs? For APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP as an example. And which value is the right one for APPCOMMAND_SAVE?

Comment: I've added some explanation in an answer below as to how the `lParam` works and why it is recorded as `0x200000` and not `0x20`

Comment: Nobody is really answering the OPs question.  An integer is stored as four bytes.  You need to send bytes and it doesn't matter if the number is decimal or hex.  Decimal or hex only applies when you are converting the number to a string.  So all you need to do is us following : byte[] bytes =  BitConverter.GetBytes(number).  The bytes are not in sequence since the Microprocessor order from lowest memory address to highest address are 1,0,3,2

Comment: @jdweng You shouldn't send bytes to `SendMessage` for `lParam`.  `lParam` should either be defined as an `IntPtr`, a `uint`, or a `ulong` depending upon use.

Comment: Well I'm fine with Marins answer. I think I capische the thing more or less. But t4n>|$ for the additional information.

Comment: @Martin : SendMessage wants bytes so you have to convert the enumeration which is an integer to bytes.  Using Intptr is a kludge and should never be used when sending an integer.  It just happens to work because both an integer and Intptr are 4 bytes.

Comment: @jdweng Having spent many years integrating with Win32 from C#, I'm fairly confident at the differing types of integration that are required.  As per my statement '_depending upon use_', the format of `lParam` varies upon what function it is being used for. An `IntPtr` is a totally legitimate type for `lParam`.  `lParam` is never an array of bytes with `SendMessage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking a little more at the `lParam` for the `WM_APPCOMMAND` API call, I can see that this contains three separate values in a bitmask:

- `cmd` - which is the specific app command you are referring to [2 bytes]
- `uDevice` - which indicates the device that generated the input [2 bytes]
- `dwKeys` - which indicates which virtual keys are depressed, if any [2 bytes]

The values for all of these is contained in `lParam` alone as a bitmask, with each one taking 2 bytes.  They are therefore structured into `lParam` as so:

```
0xAADDKK
```

Where `AA` indicates the `APPCOMMAND` being sent, `DD` indicates the `uDevice`, and `KK` indicates the `dwKeys`.

With that in mind, in order to send a command for `APPCOMMAND_SAVE` (decimal 32, hex 0x20) with no `uDevice` and no `dwKeys` the correct `lParam` value to use is:

```
0x200000
```

With regards to your other point:

> MS docs says #define WM_APPCOMMAND / 0x0319 But that doesn't seem to
> make any difference. I have somehow problems with the zero signs. How
> ever 0x319 works.

Hexadecimal numbers function as per base-10 in that leading `0`s are dropped from numbers.  Therefore hex `0x0319` is the same as `0x319` and also `0x00000319`, in the same way that in base-10, `1000` is the same number as `01000` and indeed `00000001000`.

Comment: SendMessage(fwx, WM_APPCOMMAND, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_SAVE) is my function. Is that ok?

Comment: And whats about 0x20 and 0x2 and 0x200000? ;)

Comment: @Luckylazuli That looks correct from the perspective of the `lParam` but without seeing the remainder of the code it's difficult to know.  Certainly the `APPCOMMAND_SAVE` being `0x200000` is correct, indicating that a key has been pressed (`FAPPCOMMAND_KEY` = `0x0000`) to execute `APPCOMMAND_SAVE`.

Comment: @Luckylazuli `0x20` is NOT the same as `0x2` or `0x200000`.  `32`, `2`, and `2097152` are different numbers.

Comment: I think I now understand why to add zero signs. It's about the semantics to show the number of digits. Like when you e.g. 0100 decimal is used to express that it can go up to 9999. In this respect, it makes perfect sense to add the redundant zero(s).